# makefile, one to many to one files?

Tags: makefile

I would like to process files generated from a list into a summary, using parallel processing of each intermediary file. make might be well suited for this.

Let's take an example : given a list of urls, download files, process them in parallel, and generate a report from the processed files.

example (won't work) :

```
all : report_file

report_file : $(wildcard data/*.processed)
    ...

data/%.processed : data/%.input
    ... # this should be processed in parallel

data/%.input : filelist
    download all lines of filelist to N files. 

filelist : 
    generate_list url_file > $@
```

I'd like the processing (and maybe downloading) of each file to be done in parallel and I don't know how many lines will be generated in filelist.

this won't work because the processed files do not exist when run, so rule to build report will be given an empty input.

also, it can be useful to avoid downloading files newer than 1 day and thus not process them, so makefile like dependency has a use here.

I could generate a special makefile from the list, but is there a way to do it with a single makefile ?

Comment: Why do you think `this won't work because the processed files do not exist when run, so rule to build report will be given an empty input.`? Since `report_file` depends on `*.processed`, `report_file` rule wont be executed unless all the processed files are generated. Your above code must work as it is except that it should be able to parallely process, and paralelly download files but processing and downloading wont happen parallely

Comment: no, since "all processed files" will be nothing then. And report_file thus depends on nothing ...

Comment: parallel processing and download of all files can be done with make -j normally

Comment: Yes *.processed will be absent, report_file depends on them. So makefiles runs the *.process rules. For example, consider this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27965270/makefile-do-not-recompile-files-not-updated-separate-directories/27984459#27984459 the hello would be empty initially thats why hello: rule will be executed which creates hello file

Comment: in rule `... # this should be processed in parallel` arent you creating .processed files?

Comment: Yes -j should give you parallel processing ability

Answer (score 0):

Since `report_file`'s dependencies can't be evaluated until *after* all the target-dependency information is parsed, you'll need to refresh this information again.  The only way to do this that I know of is to invoke a submake.

```
all: filelist
  $(MAKE) $(shell cat $<) #make data/a.processed data/b.processed etc...
  $(MAKE) report_file

report_file : $(wildcard data/*.processed)
    ...

data/%.processed : data/%.input
    ... # this should be processed in parallel

data/%.input :
    download all lines of filelist to N files. 

filelist :
    generate_list url_file > $@ #url list
    sed -i 's;\(.*\);\1.processed;g' $@ #append .processed to all urls
```