# Makefile : do not recompile files not updated (separate directories)

Tags: java, scala, makefile

I wonder how it's possible for a makefile, to compile only classes (Java, Scala) with changes.

My `.scala` are in the `src` directory. And when I compile, the output (`.class`) go to the `bin` directory.

In a project, when you have ~50 classes it's too long to compile all classes each time.

Do you know how to solve my problem ?

I tried maven but it seems to have the same problem.

My makefile (for Scala) :

```
SRC = src
SOURCES = $(shell find . -name *.scala)
S = scala
SC = scalac
TARGET = bin
CP = bin

run: compile
    @echo ":: Executing..."
    @$(S) -cp $(CP) -encoding utf8 App -feature


compile: $(SOURCES:.scala=.class)

%.class: %.scala
    clear
    @echo ":: Compiling..."
    @echo "Compiling $*.scala.."
    @$(SC) -sourcepath $(SRC) -cp $(CP) -d $(TARGET) -encoding utf8 $*.scala
```

**EDIT : I've found a solution : compare date of creation of .java and .bin. Here is my makefile : https://gist.github.com/Dnomyar/d01d886731ccc88d3c63**

```
SRC = src
SOURCES = $(shell find ./src/ -name *.java)
S = java
SC = javac
TARGET = bin
CP = bin
VPATH=bin

run: compile
@echo ":: Executing..."
@$(S) -cp $(CP) App

compile: $(SOURCES:.%.java=.%.class)

%.class: %.java
clear
@echo ":: Compiling..."
@echo "Compiling $*.java.."
@if [ $(shell stat -c %Y $*.java) -lt $(shell stat -c %Y $(shell echo "$*.class" | sed 's/src/bin/g')) ]; then echo ; else $(SC) -sourcepath $(SRC) -cp $(CP) -d $(TARGET) -encoding utf-8 $*.java; fi




clean:
@rm -R bin/*

# Pour supprimer les fichier .fuse* créés par sublime text
fuse:
@rm `find -name "*fuse*"`
```

Comment: In short: dont use Makefiles for Java or Scala. You'll never manage your dependencies right: there might be more than one .class for a .scala. A .class might depend on other .class files. Use Maven or SBT.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know a clear tutorial for Maren ? In the Apache Website, it's not clear. They don't explain just how to run a project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution https://gist.github.com/Dnomyar/d01d886731ccc88d3c63
It's a little bit ugly but it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You could specify the make to where to search for the dependencies using the `VPATH` variable. For your case you can assign `VPATH=bin` where the make compares the timestamp of the files under bin folder.

Example:

```
VPATH= obj
all: hello
        @echo "Makeing - all"
        touch all
hello:
        @echo "Making - hello"
        touch obj/hello
```

Output:

```
sagar@CPU-117:~/learning/makefiles/VPATH$ ls
Makefile  obj
sagar@CPU-117:~/learning/makefiles/VPATH$ make
Making - hello
touch obj/hello
Makeing - all
touch all
sagar@CPU-117:~/learning/makefiles/VPATH$ ls
all  Makefile  obj
sagar@CPU-117:~/learning/makefiles/VPATH$ make
make: 'all' is up to date.
sagar@CPU-117:~/learning/makefiles/VPATH$ touch obj/hello 
sagar@CPU-117:~/learning/makefiles/VPATH$ make
Makeing - all
touch all
sagar@CPU-117:~/learning/makefiles/VPATH$
```

Comment: It doesn't worked for me with my makefile, but I've found another solution. Thanks.

Comment: Post your answer and accept it, it will help others